# Lubrication Theory

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Basically, I'm modelling the flow of a "coating" process -- a fluid flow between a flat moving plane and a stationary cylinder, 2D, cartesian coordinates. Subscript 0 is the at the minimum height b/w the plane and the cylinder, and subscript c is at the point at which the flow leaves the moving plane-cylinder system and into the infinite-length "coating" mechanism. Diagram:
[image]

And my question: Would the height $h_0$ have to be less than $h_\infty$, i.e. would the maximal pressure generation occur at $x = 0$? And why would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that $h_\infty = h_0/2$.

I expect that $h_0$ is thin and $u$ is not too fast. The flow at $x = 0$ is dominated by viscous forces and is laminar.

In that case, the velocity of the fluid at $x = 0$ is $u$ at the surface of the plate and $0$ at the surface of the cylinder. The velocity varies linearly with height. The average velocity is $u/2$.

At $x = \infty$, the velocity of the coating is $u$.

Since the coating travels twice as fast at $\infty$, it must be half as thick. That way the same volume of fluid passes $x = 0$ and $x = \infty$ in a given time interval.